# Combo box doesn't display data from database

Tags: java, model-view-controller, netbeans

I'm creating drug store administration form for my exam, I have 2 forms, the first one for input the drugs data to inventory, the second one its like cashier, you input customer name, what drug he/she buy, how many, and the price. The problem is in the second form, there is combo box and I want to fetch the combo box with drugs data which I already input through my first form, but the combo box won't show anyting. My program run in MVC

Theese code below from model file, which I think its related to my problem.

```
// This method for display drug name into drug name combo box
public List<Transaction> fillcomboboxdrug() {
        PreparedStatement statement;
        List<Transaction> list = null;
        try {
            list = new ArrayList();
            String DISPLAYDRUG = "SELECT * FROM drug order by drug_name";
            statement = connection.prepareStatement(DISPLAYDRUG);
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Transaction T = new Transaction();
                T.setNamedrug(rs.getString("drug_name"));
                list.add(T);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return list;
    }

// This method to show drug code depend to the drug who choosen in combo box, yeah i have a form to show the drug code
    public List<Transaction> getdrugcode(String drugname) {
        PreparedStatement statement;
        List<Transaction> list = null;
        try {
            list = new ArrayList();
            String FINDDRUG = "SELECT * FROM drug where drug_name=?";
            statement = connection.prepareStatement(FINDDRUG);
            statement.setString(1, drugname);
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Transaction T = new Transaction();
                T.setCodedrug(rs.getInt("cd_drug"));
                list.add(T);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return list;
    }


// This method to show drug name depend to drug code input
    public List<Transaction> getdrugname(Integer code) {
        PreparedStatement statement;
        List<Transaction> list = null;
        try {
            list = new ArrayList();
            String FINDDRUG2= "SELECT * FROM drug where cd_drug=?";
            statement = connection.prepareStatement(FINDDRUG2);
            statement.setInt(1, code);
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
            if (!rs.next()) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Not Found!");
            } else {
                Transaction T = new Transaction();
                T.setNamedrug(rs.getString("drug_name"));
                list.add(T);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return list;
    }
```

And theese code from my controller file

```
// To call fillcomboboxdrug method from model file
public void fetchdrugcmb() {
        form.getCmbdrug().removeAllItems();
        form.getCmbdrug().addItem("-Choose-");
        for (Transaction T : model.fillcomboboxdrug()) {
            form.getCmbdrug().addItem(T.getDrugname());
        }
    }

// To call getdrugcode method from model file
    public void displaydrugcode() {
        if (form.getCmbdrug().getSelectedIndex() != 0) {
            for (Transaction T : model.getdrugcode(form.getCmbdrug().getSelectedItem().toString())) {
                form.getTxtcddrug().setText(String.valueOf(T.getCddrug()));
            }
        }
    }

// To call getdrugname method from model file
    public void displaydrugname() {
        for (Transaction T : model.getdrugname(Integer.parseInt(form.getTxtcddrug().getText()))) {
            form.getCmbdrug().setSelectedItem(T.getNmdrug());
        }
    }
```

Picture of part of my transaction form:
[image: Picture of part of my transaction form].
all I want exactly, after I choose the drug name from combo box, all related data fetch into another forms, which is price form, stock form, qty, and drug's code. But the combo box doesn't show the drug's name.
Note for the picture, sorry its in Bahasa, (1) Nama Obat = Drug Name, (2) Atau masukan kode obat pada form 'Kode Obat' = Or input drug code into 'Drug Code' form, (3) Pilih Obat = Choose Drug, (4) Kode Obat = Drug Code, (5) Harga = Price, (6) Qty = Quantity, (7) Stok = Stock